# CakePHP - Routing to admin

Tags: php, cakephp

Noob question!

I have a complete admin setup: login, authentication an so on, it's working.
So, now i need a new controller to another situation and then i create the controller named PressDownloadsController and the correct views to every action inside this new controller.

I also created the following route:

```
Router::connect('/pressdownloads', array('controller' => 'pressdownloads', 'action' => 'downloads'));
```

Inside the pressDownloads controller, there's some redirect between some actions.

When i try to open the url /pressdownloads/downloads or just /pressdownloads it just goes to admin controller and i need to login in before acess the pressdownloads area.

Why?

The Auth Settings inside UsersController (admin):

Ok. I get it.
So the auth settings:

```
      public $components = array(

    'Session',

    'Auth' => array(

        'loginAction' => array(

            'controller' => 'users',

            'action' => 'login',

            'prefix' => 'admin',

        ),

        'loginRedirect' => '/admin/events',

        'logoutRedirect' => '/admin',

        'authError' => 'Acesso negado',

        'flash' => array(

            'element' => 'admin/messages/error',

            'key' => 'auth',

            'params' => array()

        ),

        'authorize' => array('Controller'),

        'authenticate' => array(

            'Form' => array(

                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')

            )

        )

    )

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to check Auth component settings and how you split admin area from non-admin. 
Also, you may specify in your routing not to use admin prefix like this:

```
Router::connect('/pressdownloads', array('controller' => 'pressdownloads', 'action' => 'downloads', 'admin' => false));
```

Comment: Where do i find the Auth component settings?

Comment: Ok! It just needed an Allow('my_action')

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to that link after "Admin" has been enabled. Simply put you must be clicking the link from the pages served by admin.

Try adding additional parameter **"admin" => false** in your present route.

```
Router::connect('/pressdownloads', 
                array(
                   'controller' => 'pressdownloads', 
                   'action' => 'downloads', 
                   'admin' => false
                )
);
```

Comment: THanks for reply! I did it now, but still not working. It continues going to admin area, another idea?

Comment: try setting debug level to 0 if it is higher to do a cache refresh and see if this works. I am pretty sure, this is the case !!
Fingers crossed :D

Comment: also as pointed out by @Karisters below, checking Auth and Acl components may also be a good idea. ( if u r using )
Make sure, Auth allows ur action.

Comment: I have started to doubt, if u r editing the correct file ? try setting die() in that routes.php file to see if u r editing the file ryt.

Comment: Thanks Kishor! It was a stupid problem: in the application controller, my new action should be allowed to be passed without the user login. Just an Allow("my_action")...Sorry for that. But i'm learning a lot with all your answears! Thanks!